# FooterView in Specific Expanded Sections Only?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to have a footerView display when any section is expanded in a specific tableView.  Using simple footerView code the footer shows up in every section (both collapsed and expanded), and every tableView.  Is there a simple way to restrict the footer to one tableView and only when a section is expanded?

I have multiple tableViews within one ViewController, so my headers and cells are determined by logic like this:

```
//...cellForRowAt
if tableView == someTableview {
    //...cell display logic 
} else if tableView == someOtherTableView {
   //...cell display logic
}
```

Here is my sections expanding/collapsing code:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
     return someSectionTitles.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return sectionIsExpanded[section] ? (1+someArray) : 1
}
```

I'm trying to implement footer code, however it shows up in every tableView (and when sections are collapsed):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    return footerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delegate method `tableView(_:viewForFooterInSection:)` returns an `UIView?` so if you don't want a footer for a given section just return nil.  If you want to later add a footer when the section gets expanded just call `tableview.reloadSections(_:with:)` and then return a footer view in `tableView(_:viewForFooterInSection:)`.

Edit -- see example playground:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
  var sections = (0..<10).map { $0 }
  var expandedSections = Set<Int>()
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = "Cell for section \(indexPath.section) item: \(indexPath.item)"
    return cell
  }
  override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if expandedSections.contains(indexPath.section) {
      expandedSections.remove(indexPath.section)
    } else {
      expandedSections.insert(indexPath.section)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    guard expandedSections.contains(section) else {
      return nil
    }
    let footer = UIView(frame: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 500, height: 50)))
    footer.backgroundColor = .red
    return footer
  }
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    guard expandedSections.contains(section) else {
      return 0
    }
    return 44
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. This make sense, though I'm still stuck on how I could call tableView(_:viewForFooterInSection:) conditionally?

Comment: You do not call it conditionally.  you keep track of what sections are expanded, for instance: let expandedSections = Set<Int>().  in the delegate method you check if expandedSections.contains(IndexPath.section) and return a footer or nil.  whenever expandedSections is set you call reload on either the whole tableview or just for the section you changed.

Comment: I added a quick example that shows 10 section with 1 cell each.  tapping any section toggles its footer which is just a red view.

Comment: Works great; thanks!  I used tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0) as IndexSet, with: .automatic) instead of reloading the entire thing so as to not see the animated refresh on the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Before we get into the detail, you'd be better using `===` to compare your tableViews as that checks it's the same instance and not an equivalent one.

The key to this if checking the tableView and section in `viewForFooterInSection`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
  if tableView === someTableview && section == 0 {
      let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 40))
      footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
      return footerView
  } else if tableView === anotherTableView & section == 1 {
    //etc
  }
  return nil. //if none of the specific criteria for a footer are met return nil 
}
```